# Storing a reference to an object to be

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates, lambda

I don't know if this is possible at all so this is a shot in the dark.

Anyhow...

Consider having the following model:

```
    Class Model
    {
        public List<string> TheList = null;
    }
```

The List is set to null on purpose.

```
    var model = new Model();
    command.RegisterInData( model => model.TheList ); // TheList is null at this point

    model.TheList = new List<string>();
    model.TheList.Add("A value here");

    command.Execute(); // <-- Here I want to access the new list somehow
```

As said, I don't know if anything like this is possible but I would like a push in the right direction.

The function desired: I would like to tell the command where to put the result before I have a concrete object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved it, but cannot post the answer until after 8 hours since i'm apperantly a newbee... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems quite doable. Here is a variation with an even simpler accessor:

```
class Command
{
    private Func<List<string>> listAccessor;

    public void RegisterInData(Func<List<string>> listAccessor)
    {
        this.listAccessor = listAccessor;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var list = this.listAccessor();
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            Console.Log(s);
        }
    }
}

// Elsewhere
var model = new Model();
command.RegisterInData(() => model.TheList);

model.TheList = new List<string>();
model.TheList.Add("A value here");

command.Execute();
```

You'll probably want error handling for the case where `RegisterInData` is not called before `Execute`, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to delay calling the delegate passed to `RegisterInData` and call it (I guess) at `Execute`.

Comment: What would be the signature of RegisterInData. I've peeked at the linqs Where extension. public void SetReference<TSource, TKey>(Func<Tin, TKey> predicate). But I get a Types cannot be inferred by usage.

Comment: @AnkMannen: See Domenic's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could Lazy be of use here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx